# How to instantiate a unique prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new in unity and i'm trying to make an endless runner. I have "road" empty game object where "ground" is created. Ground is game object which contains some other objects and triggers.
[Ground game object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMVQs.png).
When player triggers "EndTrigger" script "GroundGenerator" creates new ground:

```
public class GroundGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject GroundPrefab;

    private bool isGenerated = false;
    private float width;
    private Transform parent;
    private Transform road;

    private void Start()
    {
        parent = transform.parent;
        road = parent.transform.parent;
        width = parent.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size.x;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !isGenerated)
        {
            AddNewGround();
            RemoveUnnecessaryGround();
        }
    }

    private void AddNewGround()
    {
        Vector3 pos = parent.position;
        GameObject newGround = Instantiate(GroundPrefab, pos + new Vector3(width, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        newGround.transform.SetParent(road);
        newGround.transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x + width, 0);
        isGenerated = true;
    }

    private void RemoveUnnecessaryGround()
    { 
        if (road.childCount > 3)
        {
            Destroy(road.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Each ground can have some randomly created barrages.
And when I create a new ground there is a copy of previous ground with name "(clone)(clone)" and with randomly generated barrages. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpqz4.png)

As far as I understand the problem is that cloned "ground" created from previous cloned object is either not from prefab or prefab changes during the game. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpqz4.png) "Ground(clone)(clone)(clone)" where BarrierSpawn with several barrages, but there have to be only one barrage per ground. Barrier creates when ground instantiated.

There is barrage system:

```
public class BarrageSpawnSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] barrageArr;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Transform spawnPoint = GetSpawnPoint();
        GameObject barrage = GetBarrage();
        Debug.Log(barrage.transform.name);

        Instantiate(barrage, spawnPoint);
    }

    GameObject GetBarrage()
    {
        return barrageArr[Random.Range(0, barrageArr.Length)];
    }


    Transform GetSpawnPoint()
    {
        return transform.GetChild(Random.Range(0, transform.childCount));
    }
}
```

Comment: You provided a good context but it is not very clear to me what you expect to happen. Do you want to get rid of the  "(clone)(clone)(clone)"?
If so, after the instantiate, you can set the `newground.name` to be whatever you like. It can be ground1, ground2 etc 
Hope that helps!

Comment: I actually don't get your problem. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for bad question, i tried to explain it more clear:Like i understand the problem is that cloned "ground" created from previous cloned object not from prefab either prefab changes during the game. You can see there have "Ground(clone)(clone)(clone)" where have BarrierSpawn with many barrages, but there is have to be only one barrage per ground. Barrier creates when ground instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. My "Ground" game object contain empty object with trigger which create new "Ground" object from prefab. Now i create separated system which generates my grounds and it works grate. But i still don't understand why it work like this.